# Writing code - Class - Is this correct/Grade my code

Tags: java, class, methods

Requirement:
Write a class, BankAccount, that has two instance variables for the name of the owner (of type String) and the balance (of type double). Add to this class the following methods:

- A constructor that initializes the BankAccount instance variables to the values in two parameters, the name of the owner and the initial balance (>=0.0).
- deposit: Given an amount (>0.0) to deposit, this method deposits it into the account.
- withdraw: Given an amount (>0.0 and <= current balance) to withdraw, this method withdraws it from the account.
- getName: This method returns the owner name.
- getBalance: This method returns tth current balance. (Don't try to format a number-just take the default.)

Include appropriate checks in your methods to ensure that the amounts deposited and withdrawn satisfy the constraints specified. Use good encapsulation guidelines.

Did I interpret this correctly and execute it correctly and if not what needs fixed and how. Any help is appreciated.

Code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class BankAccount {
static Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
private static String name;
private static double balance;


public BankAccount(String n, double b){
    System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
    n = in.nextLine();
    name = n;
    System.out.println("Enter your current balance: ");
    b = in.nextDouble();
    balance = b;
}



public void deposit(){
    System.out.println("Enter the amount you would like to deposit: ");
    double deposit = in.nextDouble();
    if(deposit > 0.0){
        balance = balance + deposit;
    }
}


    public void withdraw(){
        System.out.println("Enter the amount you would like to withdraw: ");
        double withdraw = in.nextDouble();
        if(withdraw > 0.0 && withdraw <= balance){
            balance = balance - withdraw;
        }
    }
    public static String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public static double getBalance(){
        return balance;
    }

    }
```

Comment: Not really sure the class should be prompting the user for the amount that they want to deposit/withdraw, you should be passing the values to these methods...

Comment: Ideally, you have to remove static keyword from variable and method declarations. If you have static variables, you don't need getters. Also, static name and balance means all the BankAccounts will have the same name and balance.

Answer (score 1):

> A constructor that initializes the BankAccount instance variables to the values in two parameters, the name of the owner and the initial balance (>=0.0).

Well, you have the constructor, but you override the values passed to it...

```
public BankAccount(String n, double b){
    System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
    n = in.nextLine();
    name = n;
    System.out.println("Enter your current balance: ");
    b = in.nextDouble();
    balance = b;
}
```

Should simply be...

```
public BankAccount(String n, double b){
    name = n;
    balance = b;
}
```

> deposit: Given an amount (>0.0) to deposit, this method deposits it into the account.

Your `deposit` method takes no parameters...

```
public void deposit(double amount){
    if (amount > 0.0) {
        balance = balance + deposit;
    }
}
```

> withdraw: Given an amount (>0.0 and <= current balance) to withdraw, this method withdraws it from the account.

Same as `deposit`, it takes no parameters...

```
public void withdraw(double amount){
    if (amount > 0.0 && amount <= balance) {
        balance = balance - amount;
    }
}
```

> getName: This method returns the owner name.

Check...

> getBalance: This method returns tth current balance. (Don't try to format a number-just take the default.)

Check...

Comment: Nice, I missed the parameter requirements for `deposit` and `withdraw`. Might want to include this check though: **Use good encapsulation guidelines.** I know they're not stated in the post but the fact that they're mentioned means a certain amount of encapsulation is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the static declarations. Unless you want each instance of `BankAccount` to refer to the same `balance` and `name`. Also your overloaded constructor doesn't need parameters if they aren't used/are set regardless of value.

```
public class BankAccount {
    private Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    private String name;
    private double balance;

   public BankAccount(){
       String n = "";
       double b = 0.0;

       System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
       n = in.nextLine();

       // check for null string
       if(!n.equals("")) {
           name = n;
       }

       System.out.println("Enter your current balance: ");
        // ToDo: add a check for input
       b = in.nextDouble();
       balance = b;
    }

    ...

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public double getBalance(){
        return balance;
    }
}
```

You could keep the overloaded constructor and use it in conjunction with the default constructor. Something like...

```
public BankAccount(){

   String n = "";
   double b = 0.0;

   System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
   // ToDo: add a check for input
   n = in.nextLine();

   System.out.println("Enter your current balance: ");
   // ToDo: add a check for input
   b = in.nextDouble();

   this(n, b);
}

public BankAccount(String n, double b){
     // ToDo: add checks for parameter integrity
     this.name = n;
     this.balance = b;
}
```

Comment: Other than that, does it meet all the requirements successfully?

Comment: @SeumasFrew I would say it meets the requirements halfway. Take a look at MadProgrammer's answer, he covers most if not all of what's lacking.

Answer (score 0):

If it is the normal class for normal uses then this is ok.

But if it is being used in real time financial application then method should be synchornized for thread safe operation and also remove the static variable declaration because static variable belongs to class not to the instance.

Comment: And not using double for monetary values...

Comment: It;s just a normal class for normal uses. Just an exercise to help me with classes.

Comment: @MadProgrammer The requirements state to use a double though.

Comment: @SeumasFrew Not picking on you, the answer is overly critical but misses some areas that should have been covered if they are going to go that far ;)